# read regular expression from .ini file

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a `test.ini` file with the following content:

```
[search]
pattern = ABC\d{2}-\d{3}
```

I need to use this pattern in a regular expression. 
Therefore, I want to use `configparser` to read the .ini file

```
import configparser
settings = configparser.ConfigParser()
settings.read("test.ini")
pattern = settings["search"]["pattern"]
```

but this does not give me the content regular expression string. It encodes `\` as `\\`.

```
pattern --> 'ABC\\d{2}-\\d{3}'
```

I want to replace the `\\` with `\`

However:

```
pattern.replace("\\\\","\\")
```

does not work

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `pattern` does not contain a single backslash? Remember that a `repr` string *doubles* backslashes. Are you getting your result when printing the *string* or its *representation*?

Comment: that's it. the repr got me confused. Should have simply tried it instead of trying to fix it